# rolling sum of 12 months including current month ( current month +last 11 months )

Tags: powerbi-desktop

We Want to calculate the sum of 12 month rolling sum of column name "sum of calculated injury" . In Which i want a result of sum of current month + previous 11 months data.

```
rolling sum injury = CALCULATE(
                        SUM(
                            'SafetyDatabase Origin'[Total recordable injury]),
                            DATESINPERIOD('SafetyDatabase Origin'[Year_Month],
                            LASTDATE('SafetyDatabase Origin'[Year_Month]),
                            -12,
                            MONTH
                        )
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the TOTALYTD() function
More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/totalytd-function-dax

```
TOTALYTD(
     SUM('SafetyDatabase Origin'[Total recordable injury]),
     CalendarTbl[Dates]
)
```